# Why is HTTP / 2 binary?

Tags: http, binary

Why is HTTP / 2 binary, and HTTP 1.1 text? In my opinion, they are both binary, because the computer does not have artificial intelligence and does not understand the text as such.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: I do not understand why nttp2 is considered a binary protocol if the data in both cases is represented as a bit?

Comment: binary data != binary protocol

Comment: Of course, from a computer perspective everything is binary. When you talk about binary and text you usually talk from a human perspective.

Answer (score 1):

A binary protocol is a protocol which is intended to be read by a machine rather than a human being, as opposed to a plain text protocol such as IRC, SMTP, or HTTP. Binary protocols have the advantage of terseness, which translates into speed of transmission and interpretation.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_protocol

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately everything a (non-quantum) computer holds in its memory is expressed in binary. This very sentence is stored as bits in some SQL server somewhere in a data center.

However, some bytes can be expressed as characters, while others can not. A textual format (such as source code files or other plaintext file formats) will be entirely human-readable, because all its bytes compose characters.

This is different for a binary format. Binary is not meant to be human-readable, so if you'd open an HTTP/2 stream in a text editor such as Notepad, you'd see a lot of question marks or black squares.

That's because HTTP/2 uses compression, and compression urges to make the most use of all available bits, while text doesn't.

Comment: HTTP2 is called binary only because it is compressed? HTTP2 without compression is HTTP1?

Comment: No, it's not called a binary protocol because it is compressed. It's called binary because it doesn't intend to be human-readable text.

Comment: You mean in high level of application http1.1 real-human text and http2 binary text?

Comment: For example, if send word "hello". What is the difference between HTTP1.1 and HTTP2? If HTTP1 encodes all this byte in UTF-8 it will, as I understand, 01101000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111. And what it will with in HTTP2?